# Coded UI Tests with external File and Load Tests VS2013

Tags: file, visual-studio-2013, load-testing, performance-testing, coded-ui-tests

I need to write a coded UI tests which will open a word/PDF file and fire the print command through our own printer driver. I manage to successfully record the coded UI test and it is working for one user.

Now I want to run this test as part of load test in VS2013. The coded UI tests has the dependency on word/PDF file so when I run this UI test in load test for more number of user the load tests fails as it is not able to open the multiple instances of the file.

I need advise on how this scenarios can be handled if I am using the coded UI test and load test in VS2013. Is it at all possible to automate the above scenario ?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Could you show the code used for the UI tests?

Answer (score 0):

You could have you test copy the master version of the file into a test-run-specific version and then open that copy for printing. Probably want a method with the `[TestCleanup]` attribute to delete the copy after each test execution.